# PyQt_PyObject performance overhead

Tags: qt, python-2.7, pyqt4

I have some code that I use to generate XML using the python `lxml` library.

I am using PyQt to emit a signal and pass the XML document from one class to another. The signal and slots setup works, but I keep thinking that emitting the signal with the XML object takes a long time.
I used the [line_profiler](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/line_profiler/) to take some basic measurements, and it seems that 60% of the time is spent on emitting the signal.

Is there a significant overhead in using the PyQt_PyObject to pass the XML document? Or should I convert the XML document to a string and emit this string (instead of a PyQt_PyObject)?

I am doing all this on Windows and PyQt 4.8.

Comment: Please provide a small, self-contained test case so that others can try to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks, I may struggle a little. But i'll try. I mainly wanted to know if anyone who may have tried to emit a signal using PyQt_PyObject noticed any slowdown. It may be just me. I will try and get a sample of my code though.